# Parametrising locally free bundles by locally closed subschemes of Quot schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, schemes

I am currently studying a proof by M. Kapranov, [from this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0001005), prop. 2.2.2, and I have encountered a difficulty.

We have a smooth projective scheme $S$, a codimension 1 closed subscheme $C$ in $S$ defined by the sheaf of ideals $m$, and a fixed $SL_n$-bundle $V^o$ over $S\setminus C$. (Never mind the fact that the article talks about a surface and a curve; we need to work with families.) Let $V_0$ be an $SL_n$-bundle $V$ equipped with an isomorphism $\phi:V|_{S\setminus C}\cong V^o$. Then one can prove that each pair $(V,\psi)$ with the same properties admits a couple of inclusions $m^nV\subset V_0$, $m^nV_0\subset V$, for some $n$.

Now the Author concludes that, when $n$ is fixed, a locally closed subscheme of $Quot (m^{-n}V_0/m^{n}V_0)$ parametrises all $V$'s as above. My difficulties are now:

1) Why do we have this correspondence? I expect that a pair $(V, psi)$ corresponds to the cokernel of the map $V\subset m^{-n}V_0$, but I would like to see a formal proof that this is a bijection, if this is the case.

2) If (1) works, why do we need a locally closed subscheme and not just a closed one? I think that, when the Author speaks of a locally closed subscheme, he is referring to the Grassmannian parametrising all locally free quotients of the coherent sheaf (see Nitsure, [Construction of the Hilbert and Quot schemes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0504590.pdf), page 6), but is this really locally closed? When reading Nitsure's paper, it would seem that this Grassmannian is proper (in fact projective), not quasiprojective; and moreover, that it actually coincides with the entire mentioned Quot.

Surely, imposing the condition on the determinant (we want $SL_n$-bundles) should in fact lead us to consider a smaller scheme, so this could be the reason why Kapranov talks about a "locally closed subscheme" of the mentioned Quot. But is this really a locally closed subscheme, or is it already a closed subscheme?

Thank you in advance.